# My query says that my column does not exist

Tags: mysql, sql

This works but it returns all the data and I don't need that.

```
select *
    from
        `sec_permission` a
            INNER JOIN
        `sec_role_permission` b
            on a.permission_id = b.permission_id
            INNER JOIN 
        `sec_role` c
            on b.role_id = c.`role_id`;
```

but when I specify the data

```
select `sec_permission`.`name`, `sec_role`.`name`
from
    `sec_permission` a
        INNER JOIN
    `sec_role_permission` b
        on a.permission_id = b.permission_id
        INNER JOIN 
    `sec_role` c
        on b.role_id = c.`role_id`;
```

it returns the message `Unknown column 'sec_permission.name' in 'field list`.
The column does exist.

Comment: Try `select a.name` instead of `select sec_permission.name`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you assign a table alias, you have to use that when referring to the table. Since you assign the alias `a` to `sec_permission`, you have to use `a.name`, not `sec_permission.name`.

Answer (score 3):

If you use alias in table name you should use this alias also in select  column name

```
  select a.`name`, b.`name`
  from `sec_permission` a
    INNER JOIN  `sec_role_permission` b
    on a.permission_id = b.permission_id
    INNER JOIN  `sec_role` c
    on b.role_id = c.`role_id`;
```